# Counting div's with class and returning position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with many dynamically creted div's as seen below:

```
<div class="open"></div>
<div class="open"></div>
<div class="open"></div>
<div class="open"></div>
```

I'm looking for a way to get get a position of an element (eg. If the element is the first instance of, assign id="1" if element is the second instance of, assign id="2".

I'm currently using the following jquery, but am stuck, as Im not sure where to go from here.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 var numDialogs = $('.open').length; 
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I meant to assign a ID, as in if the div is the first with that class, give it an ID of 1 ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use:

```
$('div.open').prop('id', function(i){
    return 'openElement' + (i + 1);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/f4CFS/).

I've deliberately added a prefix string because while numerical `id`s are valid under HTML5, they remain invalid under HTML4, and are difficult to select using CSS selectors.

References:

- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: Why `.prop` instead of `.attr` ?

Comment: @Colin: because, while I think both will work in this case, I regard an `id` as being a *property* of a DOM node (rather than an *attribute*). It seems to be a personal choice, though, without any specific guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Mark, you can target the element and then add an attribute like so:

```
$('.open').attr('id', numDialogs);
```

This will give it all 4's in this case, but I'll leave you to wrestle with the actual logic to implement the right numbers. Good luck.